# My JTable won't update but my Group members will

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable that is being updated by my DerbyDB that uses Vectors.  The only issue that it doesn't work, now the confusing part of this is that it is a group project and it IS working for my group members.  We are using Git to collaborate, so I'm not sure where it is breaking.  I have a fresh pull and nothing appears to be out of sync, so with that being said what else could it be? I was thinking that our Databases weren't similar (stored on our local clients) but those appears to be right, does it matter about the column names? or just how many columns there is?.  Is there anything else that I can do?

Sensor DB
[image]

This is my sensorDbClass which querys my db

```
public static List<Sensor> updateSensors(double timemark)
{
    List<Sensor> sensors = new ArrayList<Sensor>();
    try
    {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " +tableName +" WHERE time=" +timemark);            
       // System.out.println("\n----------------------------------------------------------");
    int time,id,temp,hum,light,voltage;            
        while(results.next())
        {
            time = results.getInt(1);
            id = results.getInt(2);
            temp = results.getInt(3);
            hum = results.getInt(4);
            light = results.getInt(5);
            voltage = results.getInt(6);           
            Sensor sens = new Sensor(id, temp, hum, light, voltage);
            sensors.add(sens);               
            //System.out.println(sens);
        }
        results.close();
        stmt.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    return sensors;
}
```

Updating my Jtabel using Vectors

```
public void updateTable() {
    DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
    Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
    sensors = SensorDBConnection.updateSensors(currentTime);
    System.out.println("Sensors for time = " + currentTime);

    for (Sensor s : sensors) {
        //System.out.println(s);
        Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>();
        row.add(s.getId());
        row.add(s.getTemp());
        row.add(s.getHumidity());
        row.add(s.getVoltage());            
        data.add(row);
        System.out.println("===============" +row);
    }
    Vector<String> headers = new Vector<String>();
    headers.add("ID");
    headers.add("TEMP");
    headers.add("HUMIDITY");
    headers.add("VOLTAGE");
    tableModel.setDataVector(data, headers);
    sensorTable.setModel(tableModel);       
    this.currentTime += .5;
}
```

Can anyone else think to why this is messing up?

Comment: Assuming that data is actually been loaded from the databse correctly, then what you have should work, a reason it might not work is because the table you're updating isn't the one that is actually on the screen

Comment: That's why I'm so confused I recreated the database 3 times, and loaded the data each time. It works for my group members but I can't figure it out for this.. This is what my db looks like, and it is printing on my System.out